# SQL QUERY ( SQL SERVER) Date & Time Difference

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a SQL SERVER Table which has only one  field "StartDate" the records are as follows

**
2011-07-28 19:30:00.000

2011-07-29 21:50:00.000

2011-07-25 09:20:00.000
**

What i want to do is :

SHOW RECORDS if its CURRENT DATE ( todays date ) and the time difference between current time the StartDate is not less then 5 minutes, i have written the following code but it doesnt show me the time difference ?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(day, StartDate, GETDATE()) <= 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT StartDate
FROM table
WHERE YEAR(StartDate)=YEAR(GETDATE())
AND MONTH(StartDate)=MONTH(GETDATE())
AND DAY(StartDate)=DAY(GETDATE())
AND (DATEDIFF(minute, StartDate, GETDATE()) >= 5
     OR
     DATEDIFF(minute, StartDate, GETDATE()) <= 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT StartDate
    ,GETDATE()
    ,DATEDIFF(day, StartDate, GETDATE())
    ,DATEDIFF(minute, StartDate, GETDATE())
    ,*
FROM table
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, StartDate, GETDATE()) <= 0
    AND DATEDIFF(minute, StartDate, GETDATE()) >= 5
```

Comment: `DATEDIFF(day, StartDate, GETDATE())` - wouldn't this return minus values for past days? Doesnt the user only want records for todays date?

Comment: @Curt, it would return a negative for future starts.  The first DATEDIFF ensures it is the same day (or future, I'm not sure why he put that in there).  I considered putting an ABS in there, but the poster wasn't clear about what he was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it one being DateDiff the other is DATEADD.  Judging by the way I read your question DateAdd should do it.  Here is an example;

```
    SELECT *
  FROM [dbo].[TABLE]
  WHERE [LAST_UPDATE] > DATEADD(minute,-5,GetDate())
```

Answer (score 0):

Using BETWEEN is probably a little more optimal than two AND statements (maybe not). Try not to do a calculation on each row if you don't have to. Doing DATEADD only on the current date will only be calculated once.

```
SELECT 
   whatever
FROM
   table
WHERE 
    StartDate
        BETWEEN FLOOR( CAST( GETDATE() AS FLOAT ) )
        AND DATEADD(minute, -5, GETDATE())
```

I interpret the question as looking for rows where the date is today (between the start of today) but not within the last 5 minutes (and less than 5 minutes ago). That might not be what you were going for.

Hope that helps